# Custom Color from xaml equivalent in C# code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window in a wpf application which has a grid.
The Grid has a value for it's background in hex.
I just want to check from code behind if the value of that background is what I really meant.

```
<Grid Background="#424242" Name="GridMain">
```

And in the code behind I got :

```
SolidColorBrush a = new SolidColorBrush();
var b = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#424242");
MainWindow mainWin = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
if (mainWin.GridMain.Background ==  b)
     MDark.IsChecked = true;
```

I have to mention that MDark is a radioButton.
And the condition never gets true.
I appreciate the help. :D

Comment: Why? You've set or define those colors in design time. Use the designer to compare the colors. Or define brushes as resources (e.g. `x:Key="DefaultBackgroundBrush"`) and reuse them in the application (e.g. `Grid.Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundBrush}"`.

Comment: You are comparing instance references. Use `Equals()` instead. Or compare the `Color` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing `SolidColorBrush` instances, which are obviously not the same. Compare the actual color value instead:

```
var c = (Color) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString ("#424242");
MainWindow mainWin = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
if (((SolidColorBrush) mainWin.GridMain.Background).Color == c) 
{
    MDark.IsChecked = true;
}
```